# how to register dev with specific mod?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

one misc dev of my system is 600 mod, I need it to be 666 mod ( rw for all ) ,

the chmod is usable,  however , I am wondering how to set the mod at register-time using misc_register() ,  is  chmod the only way ?

please help, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [miscdevice](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.3.3/include/linux/miscdevice.h#L50) `mode` with `S_IRUGO | S_IWUGO`.

```
  50 struct miscdevice  {
  51        int minor;
  52        const char *name;
  53        const struct file_operations *fops;
  54        struct list_head list;
  55        struct device *parent;
  56        struct device *this_device;
  57        const char *nodename;
  58        umode_t mode;
  59 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your module is not supposed to set the access level itself. The mantra is 'Policy belongs in user space, not in the kernel.'

You want to let udev (or whatever alternative for it you use) decide this.

For udev look at `man 7 udev`.

Comment: Kill the `udevd` and be surprised how `/dev` populated with device nodes from the kernel when you insert/replace your flash drive. It's `devtmpfs` magic ;)